# FileNotFoundException occured while assign DataSource in CrystalReport

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2013, filenotfoundexception

System.IO.FileNotFoundException execption thrown while assigning data source in report.
I am using visual studio 2013, C# 4.5, WinForm application. I have installed crystal report for visual studio 13.

This is code

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable("administration_CashDeskManager_Reports_ReportDataBusinessObject"));
    ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable("administration_CashDeskManager_Reports_ReportDataDetailBusinessObject"));

    Reports.CrystalReport.rptCashDeskTransactionLog Report = new Reports.CrystalReport.rptCashDeskTransactionLog();
    Report.SetDataSource(ds);
    crViewer.ReportSource = Report;
```

Error thrown on **Report.SetDataSource(ds)** command.

I think this error is version specific error.

Exception detail :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET
>   Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI
>   4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Could you catch the exception and check what file is missing? This information should be available in exception instance.

Comment: @st4hoo I edit my question please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try again after adding below section in your config:

```
<startup uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy="true">
  <supportedruntime version="v4.0" />
</startup>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use following code in App.Config File:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
</startup></p>
```