# Error with Crystal Report and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, filenotfoundexception

I was looking at this question:-
[FileNotFoundException occured while assign DataSource in CrystalReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774260/filenotfoundexception-occured-while-assign-datasource-in-crystalreport)

I have the same issue. I was not able to add a comment to get some clarification so I am posting this question. I hope that is OK with the group.

The solution was to Try again after adding below section in your config:-

```
<startup uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy="true">
  <supportedruntime version="v4.0" />
</startup>
```

Can someone please inform me where is this config and how do I add the above section to this config?

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks,
Edward

Answer (score 0):

It's in the `App.config` file located in the solution explorer window.

[image]

Edit the file by double clicking it

[image]

and add the property `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"` with its value inside the startup element.

[image]